# How to avoid redundant printings when using a decorator on nested functions?

Tags: python, decorator

I have two functions `func1` and `func2` on which I'm applying a basic timer decorator `@time_elapsed`. The problem is that `func1` is called within `func2` which cause the print of its timing too.

How can I structure my code to apply the decorator only once to `func2` while still allowing `func1` to be called independently (with a decorator of course)?

Here is my code:

```
import time
from functools import wraps

def time_elapsed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(f'{func.__name__} took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds.')
        return result
    return wrapper

@time_elapsed
def func1():
    time.sleep(2)

@time_elapsed
def func2():
    func1()
    time.sleep(3)
```

**Current behaviour :**

```
func1()
# func1 took 2.01 seconds.
```

```
func2()
# func1 took 2.00 seconds.
# func2 took 5.01 seconds.
```

**Desired behaviour :**

```
func1()
# func1 took 2.01 seconds.
```

```
func2()
# func2 took 5.01 seconds.
```

Comment: you could separate `func1` into decorated and undecorated versions, and the decorated `func1` would call the undecorated one (`_func1_implementation`), and `func2` could also call the undecorated one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle this without changing your `func*` calls, by using a counter to keep track of when the decorator has been invoked.

```py
import time
from functools import wraps


def time_elapsed(func):
    # The depth of the nested function calls to be timed and printed
    DEPTH = 1

    # Set the counter to 0 by default, if it hasn't been set yet
    time_elapsed._timer_running = 0

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # If the counter is >= the depth, call the function without timing it
        if time_elapsed._timer_running >= DEPTH:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Getting here means that the counter is less than depth. So we need to
        # increment the counter by 1.
        time_elapsed._timer_running += 1

        # Run the timer stuff just like before
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(f'{func.__name__} took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds.')

        # Cleanup the counter by decrementing it back down by 1
        time_elapsed._timer_running -= 1

        return result

    return wrapper


@time_elapsed
def func1():
    time.sleep(0.1)


@time_elapsed
def func2():
    func1()
    time.sleep(0.2)


@time_elapsed
def func3():
    func1()
    func2()
    time.sleep(0.3)


@time_elapsed
def func4():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    time.sleep(0.4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()
    print("---")
    func2()
    print("---")
    func3()
    print("---")
    func4()
```

When I run this, none of the nested print statements are shown:

```bash
$ python double_decorator.py
func1 took 0.11 seconds.
---
func2 took 0.31 seconds.
---
func3 took 0.72 seconds.
---
func4 took 1.54 seconds.
```

What's cool about this solution is that you can increase the `DEPTH` if you want to see the some of the inner calls to a degree. For example, here's what shows when I change it to `DEPTH = 2`:

```
func1 took 0.11 seconds.
---
func1 took 0.11 seconds.
func2 took 0.31 seconds.
---
func1 took 0.10 seconds.
func2 took 0.31 seconds.
func3 took 0.72 seconds.
---
func1 took 0.11 seconds.
func2 took 0.31 seconds.
func3 took 0.72 seconds.
func4 took 1.54 seconds.
```

Only the outer function and its first child are printed. The calls from `func*` doubly and triply nested in the `func4` call don't get timed, because the counter is >= the depth.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your creativity. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many functions in your codebase this might affect, but for a simple case, you could introduce a new parameter `record_time` to your functions, which is checked by the decorator.

```py
import time
from functools import wraps

def time_elapsed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if kwargs.get("record_time", False):
            print(f'{func.__name__} took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds.')
        return result
    return wrapper

@time_elapsed
def func1(record_time):
    time.sleep(1)

@time_elapsed
def func2(record_time):
    func1(record_time=False)
    time.sleep(1)

func2(record_time=True)
```